# How to use Constrained K-Means Clustering when I only have the similarity between the variables to be clustered and not the data for the variables?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, spreadsheet, similarity

I have a spreadsheet of data in which the first 12 rows in the leftmost column have 12 names in alphabetical order (descending) and the first 12 columns in the topmost row have the same names in alphabetical order (left-to-right).  These names represent the names of people who ranked something, and the values in the cells of this spreadsheet are the Kendall's Tau Similarity Coefficient between the names in the leftmost column and topmost row adjacent with the cell.  How can I use Constrained K-Means Clustering to find the similarity between these names?

Image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-mrans clustering does not work on similarity matrixes.

It needs Euclidean space vector data, in order to compute the *means* (hence the name). It cannot maximize similarities, but it minimizes the sum-of-squares of *coordinate* differences.

Also, your question is off-topic, as it is not a programming questions but you only want to use an existing program.

Since your data is so tiny it fits on a single screen, I suggest you simply brute-force test all possible solutions. Then it's trivial to add your constraints (skip candidates that don't meet your size requirements). Even without constrains, if you want 4 clusters you have much less than 4^11 possibilities, that is 4 million minus plenty of redundant permutations minus all those where clusters are too small or too large.